# ASP.NET, C#, IIS, Start Up

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I am a total Noob to to .NET. I have all my files, folders, master pages, and code behind pages in my directory... I have been building it on a local development environment that was set up by the person who was here before me. I do not know much about what the specs of the environment are.

I just tried transferring all of my files over to the server we will be running off of and I am getting a "500 - Internal server error"...

I am thinking I am missing something real basic. What can I do with my Web.config file to get rid of this error and make the page viewable?

I know the 500 error is very common and could mean alot of things, but just the most basic problem, what are you thinking?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: is iis configured for asp.net?

Comment: I'd start by making sure that IIS is configured to run asp.net and that the website/application pool is using the same .net framework version the website was compiled under.

Comment: Okay, I am fairly sure it is IIS7... I do not know if ASP.NET is set up... I would have to call the server guy... Is there a quick and easy way to check that without getting into the server control panel or back-end?

Comment: Are you seeing an ASP.net error page?  If you are, it tells you how to edit the web.config so it displays the error stack.

Comment: @bryanmac, It is not an ASP.NET error page... It is just a 500 Internal Server Error page... My web config file is also real general... it simply is setting the default pages...

Answer (score 1):

Your first step should be to check the Event Viewer on the server.  You'll get more detailed errors in there, than the generic 500 error returned to the browser.

However, some guesses include...

- IIS is not configured to run .NET at all...
- IIS is configured to run the wrong version of .NET.  (may be set to 2.0 and your app is 4.0, for example.)
- Actual errors in your code.  (Trying to read from a database without opening a connection, or any one of a million possible errors.

At any rate, the event log should have errors thrown either by IIS or by ASP.NET.  Start there.

Comment: Thank you David... How would I go about looking at the Event Viewer...

Also, I think it may be the wrong version of .NET... is that an easy upgrade process? If the server is 3.0, how do I get them to get 4.0?

Also, eliminate the errors in the code because the code is VERY dry. Literally just pages with like one word right now. I am in the process of just setting up the directories and what not.

Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisNewton Are you setting this up on a dedicated machine that you have remote access to or is this a shared hosting environment with some sort of "control panel"?

Comment: @Crunchy...I could not tell you that answer. I am a third party creating just a portion of this specific website. If I had to guess, it is a shared hosting environment with a control panel...

Comment: @ChrisNewton How are you getting the files moved to the server without knowing what or where it is?

Comment: I have FTP access to a folder/directory on the server... Also, most of the other pages are coded with cold fusion... I think the issue is that it is an older version of .NET, but I am not sure.

Comment: You're going to need to get someone on the phone that has access to the actual server. Even if .Net is installed and it's the same version you can't just drop an ASP.Net application into a sub directory and expect it to work. You'll need to make sure that directory is set up as an application under the root directory...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3712/discussion-between-crunchy-and-chris-newton)

Comment: Check with who ever is running the server and see what version of .Net is running and then ask them to make sure that the directory they've supplied you with is set up to run as an application. The server admin should know how to do this.